# Why could a 2 reputation user complete a review exercise?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, review

On the 9<sup>th</sup> of October 2016, I noticed that a user with only two reputation with practically no prior question/answer history had completed a review activity on [review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review).

I don't intend to accuse the user, [@tallal hassan](http://stackexchange.com/users/6663596/tallal-hassan) of any misconduct, quite the opposite, thanks for helping the site, but I was concerned that the usual reputation limit has not applied to them and that this might apply mistakenly to others.

Could someone look into this?

[image: Suspect Image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it was [a review of a suggested edit on their own post](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/203497), something the post's owner has a binding vote on.

Comment: Ah! My apologies, I'll accept this when I can.